# Unity with Admob and Google Play Services conflict

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project with Google Play Services added to it. Everything worked fine until I added AdMob. Now I get the error below. I have already checked for duplicated aar files, but I couldn't find any. (The list of files is also below.) I also tried deleting the Temp folder and reimporting everything in Unity Editor, also without any luck.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/jakab/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzut;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuu;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuv;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuw;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzux;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuy;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuz;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzva;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzvb;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:615)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:313)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:291)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive C:\Developing\Unity\Game\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-11.2.2\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/ads/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/ClientApi.class...
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/JavascriptEngineFactory.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/JavascriptEngineFactory$JSEngineSettableFuture.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zza.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzaa.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzab.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzac.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzad.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzae.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzaf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzag.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzah.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzai.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzaj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzak.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zze.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/js/zzz.class...
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/AdOverlayInfoParcel.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zza.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzaa.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzab.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzac.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzad.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzae.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzaf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzag.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzaj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzak.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzal.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzam.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzan.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzao.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzap.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzaq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzar.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzas.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzat.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzau.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zze.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/overlay/zzz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zza.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzaa.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzab.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzac.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzad.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzae.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzaf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzag.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzah.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzai.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzaj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzak.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzal.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzam.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzan.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzao.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzap.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzaq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzar.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzas.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzat.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzau.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzav.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzaw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzax.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzay.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzaz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzba.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbe.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzbx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zze.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzp.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzr.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzs.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzt.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzu.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzv.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzx.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzy.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/ads/internal/zzz.class...
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/google/android/gms/ads/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/google/android/gms/ads/dynamite/
processing com/google/android/gms/dynamite/descriptors/com/google/android/gms/ads/dynamite/ModuleDescriptor.class...
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/internal/
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaaa.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaab.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaad.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaae.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaaf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaag.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaah.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaai.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaaj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaak.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaal.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaam.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaan.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaao.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaap.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaaq.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaar.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaas.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaat.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaau.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaav.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaaw.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaax.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaay.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaaz.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaba.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabb.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabc.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabd.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabe.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabf.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabg.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabh.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabi.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabj.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabk.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabl.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabm.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabn.class...
processing com/google/an<message truncated>
```

The list of aar/jar files in Assets/Plugins/Android:

```
play-services-ads-11.2.2
play-services-ads-lite-11.2.2
play-services-auth-10.2.6
play-services-auth-base-10.2.6
play-services-base-10.2.6
play-services-basement-11.2.2
play-services-drive-10.2.6
play-services-games-10.2.6
play-services-gass-11.2.2
play-services-nearby-10.2.6
play-services-tasks-10.2.6
support-annotations-25.2.0
support-compat-25.2.0
support-core-ui-25.2.0
support-core-utils-25.2.0
support-fragment-25.2.0
support-media-compat-25.2.0
support-v4-25.2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

I found out that you need the same version of every aar file, but I had the versions mixed up. (For example I had play-services-ads-11.2.0 and play-services-basement-10.2.0.)

Then I found out that the Play Services Resolver downloads these files, based on the given plugin's `...Dependencies.xml` file. In my case these were
`GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml` and `GPGSDependencies.xml`. I opened both of them and looked for the version numbers in the `androidPackage` tags. In the first file it was 11.2.0 and in the second, it was 10+. I changed all occurences to the newest version, which is 11.4.0. (I got the info from here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.)

I saved the files, then the build was successful. Note that this modification must be done every time any of these plugins are added again. (If you reset or just upgrade them.)

Answer (score -1):

1. Check all `.jar` files, if there is same file.
2. A simple way: delete GooglePlaySever plugin and reset it, note the `AndroidManifest.xml` **do not cover it**.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. I checked for duplicates (wrote a simple application for it), there aren't any. I deleted both AdMob and Google Play Services plugins and hopefully all files related to them. Then I imported both packages again, first AdMob, then Google Play Services but the error keeps coming back.